# Is there a "Focus Editor" shortcut key in Xcode 4?

Tags: keyboard, xcode

Cmd-1..n are handy for changing and focusing the different navigator tabs so I don't have to take my fingers off the keyboard, but is there a shortcut for giving the focus back to the editor after focusing, say, the Project navigator with Cmd-1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aw crud, there are all sorts of "move focus to" commands in the Navigate menu that I somehow missed earlier... The combo for "Move Focus to Editor..." is Cmd-J, for example.

Comment: Cool. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have X-Code 4 installed, but Command + ~ will cycle through windows inside an application. So long as it qualifies as a window, I imagine that'd be what you need.

Comment: Sadly does nothing. Maybe it's a different combo when using a Finnish layout.

Comment: I'd play around with Command+Option+~ etc. The tilde on a Finnish keyboard is opposite the standard US English one, and it appears to need a modifier to access.

Comment: This was pretty simple in the end, posted an answer.

Comment: Xcode 4 only has one window (by default), so Cmd-` wouldn't have done anything.